# Android SDK Manager has lag in MacOS Big Sur

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager, macos-big-sur

I was working on my AS fine and cool, but when I turn my Mac to Big Sur and Android SDK manager is extremely slow, it does not working fine and it seems has a lag, on the other hand AS is working normally but when I try to modify something in SDK Manager it shows lag.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I guess you are not looking for a solution here, because we do not know how your OS is interfeering with Android Studio. I also think this is not the right place for surveys like "who else has this problem". Consider reading: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this can be solved by disabling opening documents as tabs. Here is the workaround from [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues)

> Go to the Apple Menu, select System Preferences > General. In the Prefer tabs when opening documents option, select "never". Then restart Android Studio.